# How can you remove an !important CSS property?

Tags: vue.js

I have a `v-icon` tag. I want to change his color after click event, but it

doesn't work because it set as !important in vuetify class, any idea how can I

override this property?

attached here my code:

```js
SetContinueInError(myChip, e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  target.style.setProperty("color", "yellow", "!important");
  myChip.continueInError = myChip.continueInError == true ? false : true;
},
```

```html
<v-icon @click="SetContinueInError(chip,$event)">error_outline</v-icon>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `v-icon` to `i` tag as follow and it works for me:

```js
SetContinueInError(myChip, e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  target.style.color = "yellow"
  myChip.continueInError = myChip.continueInError == true ? false : true;
},
```

```html
<i class="material-icons" style="color:gray" @click="SetContinueInError(chip,$event)">error_outline</i>
```